# Convert 'var' type in dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, var

I have one code in C# 3.5. I want to know what is the type of `postActivity`. I know this is a dictionary type, but I can't find the exact type.

This is my code.

```
var postActivity = new[] 
{                           
    new {Key="ActivityId63",
         Value=new {LikeActId= 61, CommentActId = 63, CommentLikeActId = 79 }},                           
    new {Key="ActivityId67",
         Value=new {LikeActId= 65, CommentActId = 67, CommentLikeActId = 78}},                          
    new {Key="ActivityId75",
         Value=new {LikeActId= 73, CommentActId = 75, CommentLikeActId = 80}},
    new {Key="ActivityId83",
         Value=new {LikeActId= 82, CommentActId = 83, CommentLikeActId = 84}}
}.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);

int a = postActivity["ActivityId63"].LikeActId;
```

This works fine but my problem is - this is a `var` type but I want this whole value is initialize in constructor and I want to make postactivity as a global variable.

Comment: what does hovering your pointer over var tell you?

Comment: Unfortunately, at present, it's a `Dictionary<string,#AnonymousType#>` - you need to create an actual class with `LikeActId`, `CommentActId` and `CommentLikeActId` properties and substitute that in.

Comment: What's the reason of doing an array of anonymized objects first, and then convert it to dictionary? just start with a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using anonymous types you have to use var. To get rid of it create `class`

```
public class LinkAct
{
    public int LinkActId { get; set; }
    public int CommentActId { get; set; }
    public int CommentLikeActId { get; set; }
}
```

and then your dictionary will be `Dictionart<string, LinkAct>`

```
Dictionary<string, LinkAct> postActivity = new[]
                    {                           
                        new {Key="ActivityId63", Value=new LinkAct {LikeActId= 61, CommentActId = 63, CommentLikeActId = 79 }},
                        new {Key="ActivityId67", Value=new LinkAct {LikeActId= 65, CommentActId = 67, CommentLikeActId = 78}},
                        new {Key="ActivityId75", Value=new LinkAct {LikeActId= 73, CommentActId = 75, CommentLikeActId = 80}},
                        new {Key="ActivityId83", Value=new LinkAct {LikeActId= 82, CommentActId = 83, CommentLikeActId = 84}}
                   }.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);

    int a = postActivity["ActivityId63"].LikeActId;
```

Comment: It is also possible to skip anonymous type generation step. Just initialize new Dictionary<string, LinkAct> { {"Activity", new LinkAct(...) } };